# Unable to run shell script in windows 10 with Bash on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, shell, script

I am new in windows 10 and Bash on Ubuntu and not familiar with shell script . I have to run this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash -x
mkdir -p lib
mkdir -p bin
cd nnforge
make $@
cd plain
make $@
cd ../cuda
make $@
cd ../..
cd examples
for i in ./*
do
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
        cd $i
        make $@
        cd ..
    fi
done
cd ..
cd apps
for i in ./*
do
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
        cd $i
        make $@
        cd ..
    fi
done
cd ..
```

But when I run this script with Bash, this show this errors

```
+ mkdir -p $'lib\r'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘lib\r’: No such file or directory
+ mkdir -p $'bin\r'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bin\r’: No such file or directory
+ cd $'nnforge\r'
: No such file or directorynnforge
+ make $'\r'
./make_all.sh: line 5: make: command not found
+ cd $'plain\r'
: No such file or directoryplain
+ make $'\r'
./make_all.sh: line 7: make: command not found
+ cd $'../cuda\r'
: No such file or directory../cuda
+ make $'\r'
./make_all.sh: line 9: make: command not found
+ cd $'../..\r'
: No such file or directory ../..
+ cd $'examples\r'
: No such file or directory examples
./make_all.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/make_all.sh: line 13: `do
```

How can I fix this and run script properly?

Answer (score 1):

1. This script is compiled in such a way that matters where it is running. Make sure that you run the script from the folder in which the present `nnforge` folder.
2. Another possible problem - a newline character. Try to convert newline characters in your script in unix format:

   `sudo apt-get install tofrodos
   dos2unix <your script full name>`
3. Your system does not have a `make` command to install it, and others probably necessary commands do the:

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

**P.S.** But if you try to build [nnforge](http://milakov.github.io/nnForge/) i'm afraid you will not get results in Windows 10 Bash. CUDA backend does not work accurately. Nevertheless, **good luck**!

Comment: dos2unix helped me run my script I did on Linux. Thank you!